# Vue component not showing up

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to run the code from [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) about components, but the component doesn't show up. Why not?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <todo-item></todo-item>
  </div>
  <script>
    Vue.component('todo-item', {
      template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use `<li>` but I see no `<ol>` ; moreover you'd like something like a `v-for` and `v-bind` in there. Have a good read on [this part](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components) of the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Vue instance, and tell it where in the page its root element belongs (`#app` in this case):

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
    <todo-item></todo-item>
</div>
```