# Does Vue not show in file #1 because of an unknown hidden character?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I expected both of these files to show 'Test!' and have a Vue component. Both of these files reference the exact same Vue source code. Both of these have what appear to be exactly the same Javascript. Both of these call the message key with the exact same mustache syntax.

Instead, one file shows me a `{{ message }}` while the other works as intended, showing `Test!`. Both files indicate that Vue is 'Ready. Detected Vue 2.5.21'. [Here's the result of the 'broken' file.](https://jsfiddle.net/w8o19kat/) Why is there a difference?

I've tried (on the broken file):

- Changing the CDN link where I get my Vue from (didn't work).
- Changing the variable name that the Vue is stored in from 'root' to 'app' to 'rooty' (didn't work).
- Using single parentheses vs. double for the ID and element reference (didn't work).
- Changing the location of where the Vue source code is called, putting it at the top of the body and then beneath the content, as is default (nope).
- (Vue staying alive despite deleting it). Deleting the Vue reference entirely to see if I was seeing a cached page (surprise! Even with the Vue reference gone, it still said 'Ready! Detected Vue 2.5.21').
- Hard refreshing on Chrome to get rid of the cache with the Vue scripts deleted... still detected Vue.
- Changing the file name to get a new, uncached version without Vue detected. (End the part where Vue stays alive after deleting it, i.e. Undead Vue).
- Comparing the non-working script and the working script with https://www.diffchecker.com/diff (it showed the two files as exactly the same).
- Copying the working script straight from Vue's documentation (how I made the working file, and it worked).
- Retyping the Vue script again (this also got it to work).
- Viewing the broken script on both Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Firefox Quantum (65.0b4 (64-bit)). Both are still broken.
- (Switching the coding context from Laravel Blade templates to a standalone HTML file; didn't work, so it was not Laravel's fault).
- Using JS Fiddle to make sure it's not just my machine (it isn't; it did not work).

Environment:

- Browsers mentioned above
- PHP 7.2.11
- `PHP -S localhost:8001`
- Vue 2.5.21

Broken file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <div id="rooty">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script>

        var rooty = new Vue({
            el: '#rooty',
            data: {
                message = 'Test!'
            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Working file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <div id="rooty">
        {{ message }}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script>

        var rooty = new Vue({
            el: '#rooty',
            data: {
                message: 'Test!'
            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bibliography:

- [Learn Vue 2: Step By Step](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/1)
- [Vue component not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152243/vue-component-not-showing-up)
- [Simple html with vue.js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755269/simple-html-with-vue-js-not-working)
- [Introduction to Vue (Vue documentation)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being a simple `semicolon`. On your broken file if you change `=` to `:` on the `data` it would work as expected.

```
  var rooty = new Vue({
            el: '#rooty',
            data: {
                message : 'Test!' //it is not message = 'Test!', but message: 'Test'
            }

        })
```

Here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jayas_godblessall/7e2g1ykd